# Unable to display Json data using Promise and AJAX requests fetch API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, promise

Hi i am having issues retrieving the json data from my web services using a Promise and AJAX requests fetch API, the code fails on

```
return response.json();
```

The console shows this error

> ajaxPromisesTask2.html:47 GET ***/hits.php?artist=dav 401 (Authorization Required)

but i have many working scripts that connect to the same webservice and retrieve the Json data, but this is my first Promise version using the inbuilt API. what am i doing wrong ?

link to Json webservice:
[Json file](https://edward2.solent.ac.uk/~martine/year3/hits.php?artist=Oasis)

> FYI, I have tried Json.parse(response);
>   and JSON.stringify(response);

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function ajaxrequest()
{   
    var a = document.getElementById("artist").value;
    fetch('/hits.php?artist=' + a).then(ajaxresponse).
        then(showJSONResults).catch(ajaxerror);
}

function ajaxresponse(response) 
{
    return response.json(); 
}

function ajaxerror(code) 
{
    alert('error; ' + code);
}

function showJSONResults(jsonData) 
{
    var output = "<table style='width:100%'> <tr> <th>Title</th> <th>Artist</th> <th>Chart position</th> </tr>"; 
    for(var i=0; i < jsonData.length; i++) 
    {
        output = output + ' <tr> <td>' + jsonData[i].title + '</td><td>' + jsonData[i].artist + '</td><td>' + jsonData[i].chart + '</td></tr>';
    }
    output = output + "</table>";
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="info">
    <input id="artist" /> <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="ajaxrequest()" />  
<div/>
<div id="response"><div/>
```

Comment: If it fails parsing the response then check the console and the network tab for any errors. Does the API require cookies (`fetch` doesn't send or receive cookies by default)? Is the response valid JSON?

Comment: i tried to display the response in the console and it instead says: ajaxPromisesTask2.html:47 GET https://edward2.solent.ac.uk/hits.php?artist=dav 401 (Authorization Required) and underlines: fetch('/hits.php?artist=' + a).then(ajaxresponse).

Comment: again this file is in the same place as all the others and they do not get this issue, or any issues. why is it saying 401 when i dont need to enter anything ?

Comment: `fetch` doesn't send or receive cookies by default -> [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: oh ok what is the solution, please if there is one ?

Comment: Please don't edit things like "SOLVED" into your questions, and please don't fundamentally change your question after you've asked it. Questions cannot be moving targets for people working on answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, `fetch` **won't send or receive any cookies** from the
>   server, resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on
>   maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the *credentials* [init
>   option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters)
>   must be set).
>
> Source: [Using Fetch - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

---

You have to supply an object with a `credentials` property whose value is set to `same-origin` to submit the authorization cookie.

```
function ajaxrequest()
{ 
    var a = document.getElementById("artist").value;
    fetch('/hits.php?artist=' + a, { credentials: 'same-origin' })
        .then(ajaxresponse)
        .then(showJSONResults)
        .catch(ajaxerror);
}
```